# Grunt command always run the same Gruntfile

Tags: gruntjs

i'm trying to learn Grunt and i create a file, cd to there, and use the grunt command, but doesn't execute my file, but executes other that belongs to a personal project made with yeoman, and no matter the place in the terminal, always run that project. I use:

`$ grunt --base "/Users/user/Documents/Ejercicios angular/Ui-routes-tutorial/"`

and it shows me:

```
Warning: Task "newer:jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.

Execution Time (2014-04-18 13:41:21 UTC)
loading tasks  3ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 60%
default        2ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 40%
Total 5ms
```

Here is my file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
   pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  uglify: {
     options: {
      banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
    },
     build: {
       src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
      dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
    }
  }
 });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

 // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);

};
```

The error shows Task "newer:jshint" not found, but in my file i don't use that! Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried CD to the directory of the project, then do a npm install to ensure all the modules defined in the package file are installed, and then run your grunt command?

Comment: Yeah, like i said, i cd to there (i don't know if you can say that in English, sorry) and i did npm install, The error shows Task "newer:jshint" not found, but in my file i don't use that! Thanks for your answer, any other please??

Comment: Can you try a grunt --verbose and see if this uncovers any additional info?

Comment: ok, It shows to many information, everything success, because it runs one of my old angular projects created with yeoman, it runs too many task, like grunt-autoprefixer, grunt-contrib-cssmin, and  too much more.

Comment: OK, does the path look correct in the console when running that command? Sounds like the grunt command is firing a different package.  When you installed the grunt CI, did you install it globally?

Comment: After too many, i discovered a Gruntfile.js in my user folder created by yeoman accidentally, grunt command works in the folder it should, but now say `A valid Gruntfile could not be found.` `Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile. ` and its the same as the http://gruntjs.com/getting-started, What more can i do? Thanks